# Android Eclipse compiler do not see the layouts and ids

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The problem is that the Eclipse compiler do not see any layout or ids, or even strings and values in res folder, though R class is generated well (I've opened it, but of course didn't change enything). So I've tried to Clean and Build project and even restart Eclipse, compare the ids - the problem is still Eclipse don't see anything from res. 
What should I do? May be someone solved this yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK generates resource classes in the root package of your project. So, if your root package is com.project, and you're trying to use it from some other package (which is or is not directly under the root package), you need to import com.project.R.

Comment: But then zuesakm should see an error when he tries to use R. Or he has imported a different R class

Answer (score 1):

i think importing `import android.R;` you can't see any ids or layouts or strings

change it in `import com.companyname.projectname.R;`

- Get package name from android manifest file.and import like  `import packageName.R;`